# Python Snake Tutorial, Tail/Speed

Tags: python, performance, variables

I am trying to add a tail to my snake (at the very end use a triangle image rather than a square fill). While I think I got the code to work for the most part, I was seeing that if I changed directions, the last few seconds the tail would "disconnect"  from the body. (tail points right and body going down leaves a gap). I tried to fix this by upping my FPS which seemed to work; however I wanted the snake speed to be the same as before and since I doubled the FPS I would have to 1/2 the speed. When I did that however, my collision detection was out of sync and if I slowed it down my body would draw over my face, and if I sped up I would have my body getting disconnected (block, space, block).  I have tried it a few different ways so any help would be appreciated.

Please note that block_speed = 10, and if I manually type 10 it works, but if I change to 5 or 20, or if I change to a variable with value of 5 or 20 (say speed for example), the code does not work.

Code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import*
import time
import random
import os

pygame.init()

#GUI Settings
display_Width = 800
display_Height = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_Width,display_Height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Gluttonous Snake")
gameicon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
potatoimg = pygame.image.load('potato.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(gameicon)
FPS = 15

direction = "up"
#set path to where to .py/.exe is
abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
print(dname)
snakeheadimg = pygame.image.load('snakehead.png')
snaketailimg = pygame.image.load('snaketail.png')
appleimg = pygame.image.load('apple.png')

#define colors
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)
eggwhite = (255,255,204)
lightgrey = (242,242,242)

#Game Variables
block_size = 10
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def game_intro():
    intro = True

    x = 500
    y = 400
    x_dir = "left"
    while intro:
        gameDisplay.fill(eggwhite)
        gameDisplay.blit(potatoimg, (50, 25))
        message_to_screen("Potato Productions Presents...", black, -100, size=45)
        message_to_screen("Gluttonous Snake", green, -25, size=75)
        message_to_screen("A game made by a potato to run on a potato", black, 50, size=25)
        message_to_screen("Press C to Start!", red, 75, size=25)
        gameDisplay.blit(gameicon, (x, y))
        if x_dir == "left":
            if x > 0:
                x -= 10
            else:
                x_dir = "right"
        else:
            if x < 500:
                x += 10
            else:
                x_dir = "left"

        if x < 125 or x > 375:
            y -= 9.66
        else:
            y += 10


        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
                intro = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    intro = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()


def  pickFont(name,size):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(name, size, bold=False)
    return font
    #font size  = 25
    #font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",size=25)


def snake(snakelist):
    # faster GPU method is
    # gameDisplay.fill(red, rect=[200,200,50,50])

    if direction == "left":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeheadimg,90)
    if direction == "right":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeheadimg,270)
    if direction == "down":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeheadimg,180)
    if direction == "up":
        head = pygame.transform.rotate(snakeheadimg,0)

    gameDisplay.blit(head,(snakelist[-1][0],snakelist[-1][1]))

    #-1 because we are drawing that above
    # for XnY in snakelist[:-1]:
    #     #gameDisplay.fill(green, rect=[lead_x, lead_y, block_size, block_size])
    #     gameDisplay.fill(green, rect=[XnY[0], XnY[1], block_size, block_size])

    # -1 because we are drawing that above
    if len(snakelist) >= 2:
        for XnY in snakelist[1:-1]:
            gameDisplay.fill(green, rect=[XnY[0], XnY[1], block_size, block_size])
        if direction == "up":
            tail = pygame.transform.rotate(snaketailimg, 180)

        if snakelist[1][0] > snakelist[0][0]:
            tail = pygame.transform.rotate(snaketailimg, 90)
        elif snakelist[1][0] < snakelist[0][0]:
            tail = pygame.transform.rotate(snaketailimg, 270)
        elif snakelist[1][1] > snakelist[0][1]:
            tail = pygame.transform.rotate(snaketailimg, 0)
        elif snakelist[1][1] < snakelist[0][1]:
            tail = pygame.transform.rotate(snaketailimg, 180)
        gameDisplay.blit(tail, (snakelist[-len(snakelist)][0], snakelist[-len(snakelist)][1]))

def text_objects(text, color,size):
    font = pickFont("comicsansms", size)
    textSurface = font.render(text,True,color,size)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_to_screen(msg,color,y_displace=0, size=25):
    #True is anti-aliasing
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, color, size)
    textRect.center = (display_Width/2),(display_Height/2) + y_displace
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf,textRect)

def gameLoop():
    # set up variables
    global direction
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    lead_x = display_Width / 2
    lead_y = display_Height / 2

    coinflip = random.randint(0, 1)
    if coinflip == 0:
        coinflip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if coinflip == 0:
            lead_x_change = **10**
            lead_y_change = 0
            direction = "right"
        else:
            lead_x_change = -**10**
            lead_y_change = 0
            direction = "left"
    else:
        coinflip = random.randint(0, 1)
        if coinflip == 0:
            lead_x_change = 0
            lead_y_change = **10**
            direction = "down"
        else:
            lead_x_change = 0
            lead_y_change = -**10**
            direction = "up"

    #lead_x_change = 0
    #lead_y_change = 0
    #the 10 is round to 10
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, display_Width - block_size, 10)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, display_Height - block_size, 10)
    snakelist = []
    snakelength = 1

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            #message_to_screen("Game over \n Press C to play again or Q to quit", red)
            message_to_screen("Game Over", red, y_displace=-50, size=75)
            message_to_screen("Press C to play again or Q to quit",black,y_displace=50,size=25)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        gameExit = True
                        gameOver = False

                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        gameLoop()
                        #gameOver = False



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #shows every mouse move and key pressed
            #print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                gameOver = False

            #check for single depress of keys
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    #lead_x -= 10
                    #this is so they can't back over themselves
                    if lead_x_change != **block_size**:
                        lead_x_change = - **block_size**
                        lead_y_change = 0
                        direction = "left"
                #elif is only tested if the ifs and elifs above it are not true
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    #lead_x += 10
                    if lead_x_change != -**block_size**:
                        lead_x_change = **block_size**
                        lead_y_change = 0
                        direction = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    if lead_y_change != **block_size**:
                        lead_x_change = 0
                        lead_y_change = -**block_size**
                        direction = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    if lead_y_change != -**block_size**:
                        lead_x_change = 0
                        lead_y_change = **block_size**
                        direction = "down"

            # user releases key
            # if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                   # lead_x_change = 0

        #Ends the game once the square has left the window
        if lead_x >= (display_Width - block_size) or lead_x <= 0 or lead_y >= (display_Height - block_size)  or lead_y <= 0:
            print("snake left at " + str(lead_x)+","+str(lead_y))
            lead_x_change = 0
            lead_y_change = 0
            gameOver = True



        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(lightgrey)



        snakehead = []
        snakehead.append(lead_x)
        snakehead.append(lead_y)
        snakelist.append(snakehead)

        if len(snakelist) > snakelength:
            del snakelist[0]

        #-1 because last element is the head
        for eachSegement in snakelist[:-1]:
            if eachSegement == snakehead:
                print("snake eats itself")
                gameOver = True

        #draw snake first so if apple spawns on it I can still see it
        snake(snakelist)

        #gameDisplay.fill(red, rect=[randAppleX, randAppleY, block_size, block_size])
        gameDisplay.blit(appleimg,(randAppleX, randAppleY))

        pygame.display.update()

        #better collison detection as part of the snake can go over part of the apple
        # if lead_x >= randAppleX and lead_x + block_size < randAppleX + block_size or lead_x + block_size  >= randAppleX and lead_x + block_size < randAppleX + block_size:
        #     if lead_y >= randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + block_size or lead_y + block_size >= randAppleY and lead_y + block_size < randAppleY + block_size:
        if lead_x >= randAppleX:
            if lead_x + block_size <= randAppleX + block_size:
                if lead_y >= randAppleY:
                    if lead_y + block_size <= randAppleY + block_size:
                        print("nom nom nom")
                        randAppleX = random.randrange(0, display_Width - block_size, 10)
                        randAppleY = random.randrange(0, display_Height - block_size, 10)
                        snakelength += 1

        #used to make FPS
        clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

game_intro()
gameLoop()
```

Reply to answer provided:

Great thanks I will look into this. Were you able to figure out why I can't adjust the speed though? Seems weird it would draw the body over the head if I slow down the speed, or it will leave gaps if I speed it up. The part were I was adjusting the speed was in bold

Comment: What are the "few different ways" that you have tried? Might want to update your post with that info, as well as what happened when you tried them, so we have an idea. Generally when seeking help in coding, it's best to format your questions as "What I want / What I tried / What I expected / What I actually Got"

Comment: I tried to change the FPS variable, and also the lead_x/y_change. Both increasing and decreasing each variable as well as both. I tried them by /2 and *2 as well as multiples of 10 thinking there might be something with it needing to be a multiple of 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably smooth things a bit (and make your code clearer) by doing the following:

1 - store the tail (head) rotated images:

```
tail_left = pygame.transform.rotate(snaketailimg, 180)   # choose appropriate rotation
tail_right = ...
tail_up = ...
tail_down = ...
```

2 - determine which direction the snake goes, and look up the images from a dict (for instance)

```
tail_oriented_images = {'left': tail_left, 'right': tail_right, ...}
...
tail_direction = get_tail_direction()   # to be extracted
```

3- then replace the if cascade in `snake(snakelist)` with:

```
tail = tail_oriented_images[tail_direction]
```

4- Do the same for the head direction